# HELP. Pex killed my projects and GAC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, reference, pex

Really not sure what's happened here, but I was playing with pex and moles in a project I then got pex to generate tests for the web client which is MVC. This caused all sorts of build problems in the project so I reverted the project back (source control using HG). I still got all the same build issues, which included references missing and other errors relating to the missing references.  When I deleted the references in the solution, things like system.web.mvc and system.componentmodel.dataannotations, and tried to re-add them from GAC they are not visible in the GAC.  I can't understand how pex can have done this.  Now all of my projects in visual studio have the same issues with DataAnnotations, Mvc and a couple of other references? I can't do anything with any of them.  I've also noticed that all the links to the pex forums seem to be dead?

I think I can recover most of my work as it's a VM and I have a snapshot that is not to old plus I work out of dropbox so can get all my source back.  I just can't understand how this has happened any body have any advice, experiences of the same nature.  I was really starting to enjoy pex and moles but this has put me right off.

Comment: Taken me all day and got no where with this.. Still can't figure out what went wrong. So gladd it was a VM but still lost nearly 3 days of work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the Parameterized Unit Test macro has deleted the System.Web.Mvc.dll and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll from the file system.

You  need to get the assemblies from another machine and manually add System.Web.Mvc.dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.dll to C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\ respectively.

Hope that works out for you.

Comment: Thanks Amar,+1 as This probably would have worked but being on a virtual machine I rolled back to a snapshot.  Why would the parameter tests delete anything let alone system files?? It has stopped my pex usage in its tracks, seems very dangerous

Comment: On my system, it looks like the whole .NET 4.0 folder under "C:\program files (x86)\Reference Assemblies" is missing. Woh.